# Валидация шаблонов url на JavaScript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Как лучше всего валидировать url по шаблонам, содержащим регулярки подобного вида:

```
/item/:id(\d+)
```

Причем необходимо выдергивать название переменной из шаблона (id) и присваивать ей соответствующее значение. Был бы благодарен за примеры кода.

Comment: лучше взять готовую популярную имплементацию роутера где эти проблемы решили за вас со всеми эдж кейсами

Comment: @УткаУчитсяУму, да, для production это было бы самое оптимальное решение. Но у меня интерес чисто академический: мне интересно, как реализовать подобное наиболее оптимально, красиво и правильно.

Comment: @posix, написать свой парсер!